# Checking if a div is visible within viewport using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use jquery to check if Div RED is within the viewport, and if not, then check if  Div ORANGE is in the viewport. The function I am using works great if there is only one IF statement, but when I add another IF ELSE statement, it wont work.

here is the function:

```
$.fn.isOnScreen = function(){

    var win = $(window);

    var viewport = {
        top : win.scrollTop(),
        left : win.scrollLeft()
    };
    viewport.right = viewport.left + win.width();
    viewport.bottom = viewport.top + win.height();

    var bounds = this.offset();
    bounds.right = bounds.left + this.outerWidth();
    bounds.bottom = bounds.top + this.outerHeight();

    return (!(viewport.right < bounds.left || viewport.left > bounds.right || viewport.bottom < bounds.top || viewport.top > bounds.bottom));

};
```

here is the code I added to check and see if div red or div orange is within the viewport

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($('.red').isOnScreen() === true) { 
       $('.red').remove();
    } else if ($('.orange').isOnScreen() === true) {
       $('.orange').remove();   

    }
});
```

here is a jfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/wN7ah/453/

Comment: Why don't you use the one given on their site: http://jsfiddle.net/moagrius/wN7ah/

Comment: Well I want it to check which div is on the screen when the user scrolls and not when the user clicks.

Comment: Where did you mention about the click function ? You are doing it on window scroll...Do you want it on click ?

Comment: I want to check on scroll, not on click.

Comment: That's what I did ...check answer

Comment: Since this was the top result of my search I added a modern answer.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here is the working versions: http://jsfiddle.net/wN7ah/455/

Function that does the magic:

```
$.fn.isOnScreen = function(){

    var win = $(window);

    var viewport = {
        top : win.scrollTop(),
        left : win.scrollLeft()
    };
    viewport.right = viewport.left + win.width();
    viewport.bottom = viewport.top + win.height();

    var bounds = this.offset();
    bounds.right = bounds.left + this.outerWidth();
    bounds.bottom = bounds.top + this.outerHeight();

    return (!(viewport.right < bounds.left || viewport.left > bounds.right || viewport.bottom < bounds.top || viewport.top > bounds.bottom));

};
```

Usage:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
   if ($('.orange').isOnScreen() == true) {
     //alert("removing orange");
     $('.orange').remove();   
   }
  if ($('.red').isOnScreen() == true) { 
    //alert("removing red");
    $('.red').remove();
   } 

});
```

If any orange or red is present in onscreen it'll remove them.

If you want to check when it's removed, add alert before removing: http://jsfiddle.net/wN7ah/457/

Comment: Please consider adding the "isOnScreen" extension in the answer, rather than the jsfiddle. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

We can do it with pure javascript function like below

```js
function elementInViewport2(el) {
  var top = el.offsetTop;
  var left = el.offsetLeft;
  var width = el.offsetWidth;
  var height = el.offsetHeight;

  while(el.offsetParent) {
    el = el.offsetParent;
    top += el.offsetTop;
    left += el.offsetLeft;
  }

  return (
    top < (window.pageYOffset + window.innerHeight) &&
    left < (window.pageXOffset + window.innerWidth) &&
    (top + height) > window.pageYOffset &&
    (left + width) > window.pageXOffset
  );
}
ele = document.getElementById('visb_true');
console.log("visible: ", elementInViewport2(ele))
ele = document.getElementById('visb_false');
console.log("visible: ", elementInViewport2(ele))
```

```css
#visb_true{
    color: green;
    font-weight: 800;
}

#visb_false{
    color: red;
    font-weight: 800;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<p> hello </p>
<p> hello </p>
<p id="visb_true"> hello </p>
<p> hello </p>
<p> hello </p>
<p> hello </p>
<p> hello </p>
<p> hello </p>
<p> hello </p>
<p> hello </p>
<p> hello </p>
<p> hello </p>
<p> hello </p>
<p> hello </p>
<p> hello </p>
<p> hello </p>
<p> hello </p>
<p> hello </p>
<p> hello </p>
<p> hello </p>
<p> hello </p>
<p> hello </p>
<p> hello </p>
<p> hello </p>
<p> hello </p>
<p> hello </p>
<p> hello </p>
<p> hello </p>
<p> hello </p>
<p> hello </p>
<p> hello </p><p> hello </p>
<p id="visb_false"> hello </p>
<p> hello </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: javascript only solution was a lifesaver thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The modern way to do this is by using the [Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API). This is an excellent documentation, the following are basically just excerpts from it. [It works with all modern browsers.](https://caniuse.com/?search=intersection%20observer)

First, create an Intersection Observer:

```
let options = {
    root: document.querySelector('#scrollArea'), // null for entire viewport 
    rootMargin: '0px',
    threshold: 1.0
}
let observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, options);
```

Then target an element (or multiple elements) to watch:

```
let target = document.querySelector('#watchItem');
observer.observe(target);
```

Lastly, the callback. It receives a list of all watched items `entries`. Check the value of the `isIntersecting` property to see if the entry represents an element that currently intersects with the root.

```
let callback = (entries, observer) => {
    entries.forEach(entry => {
        if(entry.isIntersecting) {
            // Do your thing
        }
    });
};
```