# HTML style="overflow:hidden" accessing elements inside overflow with JavaScript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a `<div>` that has `style="overflow:hidden"` and the `<body>` is a fixed size, the idea for it is to be a multi-screen display with no UI.

Is there a way to access these "non-visible" elements to know which is the first element that doesn't fit on the page?

I'm sure its probably something very simple, but I'm new to html and JavaScript so it makes searching for things difficult.

Comment: `overflow:hidden` is not the same as hidden element.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20644029/checking-if-a-div-is-visible-within-viewport-using-jquery

Comment: I didn't realize they were different things, as I said new to this. I just assumed they were hidden because if I inspect elements after the page has been rendered anything that doesn't fit on the page is no longer in the html.

Answer (score 2):

You can use that plugin https://github.com/teamdf/jquery-visible/.

To check if an element is visible:

```
$('element').visible();
```

To get all elements instead of testing one you could do something like that:

```
$('elements').filter(function( index ) { return $(this).visible(); });
```

Comment: Is there not a way to do it without the plugin?

Comment: There, a pure JS solution : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123999/how-to-tell-if-a-dom-element-is-visible-in-the-current-viewport

Comment: I guess that's something similar to what the plugin does

Answer (score 0):

If you don't wanna use a jQuery plugin (answer provided Joanvo), you can use this way, answered on SO : 
[How to tell if a DOM element is visible in the current viewport?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123999/how-to-tell-if-a-dom-element-is-visible-in-the-current-viewport/7557433#7557433)

*It's pretty much the same.*

**Note that `getBoundingClientRect()` became the best pratice to get viewport dimensions.**

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way

```
var winHeight = $(window).height();

var firstElement = null;
function findFirstHiddenElement(ele)
{
  if(firstElement != null) return;
  if(ele.offset().top>winHeight){ 
    firstElement = ele;
    return true;
  }
  else{
    ele.children().each(function(){
      if(firstElement != null) return false;
    if($(this).children().length>0)  findFirstHiddenElement($(this));
   });
  }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
   findFirstHiddenElement($("body"));
});
```

Answer (score -3):

you can try this code

```
var hiddenElements = $( "body" ).find( ":hidden" );
```

in some browser scripts are hidden elements for that

```
var hiddenElements = $( "body" ).find( ":hidden" ).not( "script" );
```

oki now I understood.

I think the top of overflow:hidden element is compare with body height then its possible to group all the hidden elements. try this. change as per your needs

```
var bodyHeight = $("body").height();
var hiddenElments = new Array();

$("body").find("*").each(function(){
    if ($(this).position().top > h)
        hiddenEls.push($(this));
});
```

Comment: They are not hidden, just not visible in the viewport

Comment: `$("body").find(":hidden")` can be simplified into `$("body :hidden")`, even though question is not about it.