# How to slide div in when it is in viewport and then out when it is no longer in viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to have a div slide in and out of view on scroll. It would slide into view when it is in the viewport and out of view when it is out of the viewport. When it slides out, it will be replaced with another div(next div in code) sliding in.

The problem I am having is each div i want to show/hide shares a class with the next div. So, my code is showing/hiding all 3 divs at once instead of showing/hiding according to there place in the viewport.

Thanks for any help!

HTML:

```
    <body>
    <header id="legendary__intro">
      <div class="section__title">
        <h1 class="header__title">Lorem Ipsum</h1>
        <p class="header__description"Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</p>

        <div class="header__subtitle uppercase">
          <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
        </div>
        <div class="line"></div>
        <i class="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </div>
    </header>
      <main class="main">
        <section class="century">
          <div class="decade">
            <div class="year">
            <div class="year__copy slide__left">
                <div class="year__data">
                  <h2 class="date">2018</h2>
                  <h3 class="subtitle">Lorem Ipsum</h3>
                  <p class="description">Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="year__images slide__right">
                <div class="images is-hidden">
                  <img class="images__image" src="https://placebear.com/600/600">
                  <img class="images__image" src="https://placebear.com/600/600">
                  <img class="images__image" src="https://placebear.com/600/600">
                </div>
                <div class="fs__icon" title="Expand/Close"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="year">
            <div class="year__images slide__left">
              <div class="images">
                <img class="images__image" src="https://placebear.com/600/600">
                <img class="images__image" src="https://placebear.com/600/600">
                <img class="images__image" src="https://placebear.com/600/600">
              </div>
              <div class="fs__icon" title="Expand/Close"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="year__copy slide__right">
              <div class="year__data">
                <h2 class="date">Lorem Ipsum</h2>
                <h3 class="subtitle">Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</h3>
                <p class="description">Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="year">
            <div class="year__copy slide__left">
              <div class="year__data">
                <h2 class="date">2016</h2>
                <h3 class="subtitle">Lorem Ipsum</h3>
                <p class="description">Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum  Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="year__images slide__right">
              <div class="images">
                <img class="images__image" src="https://placebear.com/600/600">
                <img class="images__image" src="https://placebear.com/600/600">
                <img class="images__image" src="https://placebear.com/600/600">
              </div>
              <div class="fs__icon" title="Expand/Close"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </main>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../bower_components/slick-carousel/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="slick-lightbox.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    triggerAnimation();

    function triggerAnimation(){
      $(window).on('scroll', function(){  
        window.requestAnimationFrame(animateSlide);
      });
    } 

    function animateSlide(){
      var divTop = $(window).scrollTop(),
      divBottom = $('.year').offset().top + $('.year').outerHeight();

      $('.year').each(function(){
        if (divBottom > divTop) {
          $('.slide__left').css({
            '-moz-transform': 'translate3d(0px, 0, 0)',
            '-webkit-transform': 'translate3d(0px, 0, 0)',
            '-ms-transform': 'translate3d(0px, 0, 0)',
            '-o-transform': 'translate3d(0px, 0, 0)',
            'transform': 'translate3d(0px, 0, 0)',
            'opacity': 1,
            'left': 0
          });

          $('.slide__right').css({
            '-moz-transform': 'translate3d(0px, 0, 0)',
            '-webkit-transform': 'translate3d(0px, 0, 0)',
            '-ms-transform': 'translate3d(0px, 0, 0)',
            '-o-transform': 'translate3d(0px, 0, 0)',
            'transform': 'translate3d(0px, 0, 0)',
            'opacity': 1,
            'right': 0
          });
        } else {
          $('.slide__left').css({
            '-moz-transform': 'translate3d(0px, 0, 0)',
            '-webkit-transform': 'translate3d(0px, 0, 0)',
            '-ms-transform': 'translate3d(0px, 0, 0)',
            '-o-transform': 'translate3d(0px, 0, 0)',
            'transform': 'translate3d(0px, 0, 0)',
            'opacity': 0,
            'left': '-150px'
          });

          $('.slide__right').css({
            '-moz-transform': 'translate3d(0px, 0, 0)',
            '-webkit-transform': 'translate3d(0px, 0, 0)',
            '-ms-transform': 'translate3d(0px, 0, 0)',
            '-o-transform': 'translate3d(0px, 0, 0)',
            'transform': 'translate3d(0px, 0, 0)',
            'opacity': 0,
            'right': '-150px'
          });
        }
      });
    }

    $('.images').on('init reInit afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
      console.log(event);

      var i = (currentSlide ? currentSlide : 0) + 1;
      slick.$nextArrow.text(i + '/' + slick.slideCount + ' next');
    });

    $(".images").slick();
    $('.images').slickLightbox({
      src: 'src',
      itemSelector: 'img',
      prevArrow: false,
      nextArrow: false
    });
  });
```

SCSS:

```
//
// App
// ----------------------------------------
html, body{
  background-color: #efefef;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
.uppercase{
  text-transform: uppercase
}
header{
  color: #fff;

  .section__title{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;

    h1{
      font-size: 48px;
    }

    p {
      font-size: 20px;
    }

    .header__subtitle{
      margin-top: 100px;
      padding: 10px;
    }

    .line{
      width: 50px;
      height: 1px;
      background-color: #fff;
      border-radius: 1px;
    }
    i{
      padding: 20px;
    }
  }

}

#legendary__intro{
  background: url(../images/fpo-spotlight.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
main{padding: 15px;}
.year {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  padding: 40px 0;

  &__copy {
    flex: 0 0 50%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    margin: auto;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    transform: translate3d(0px, 30px, 0);
    opacity: 0;

    &__.active{
      transform: translate3d(0px, 0, 0);
      opacity: 1;
    }

    .year__data{
      width: 75%;
      line-height: 1.5;
      letter-spacing: 1px;

      .date, .description{
        font-size: 26px;
      }
      .subtitle{
        font-size: 48px;
        margin: 0;
      }
    }
  }

  &__images {
    align-items: flex-end;
    display: flex;
    flex: 0 0 50%;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    max-height: 600px;

  }

  .slide__left{
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all .8s ease-in-out;
    transform: translate3d(0px, 30px, 0);
    opacity: 0;
    left: -150px;
    position: relative;
  }
  .slide__right{
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all .8s ease-in-out;
    transform: translate3d(0px, 30px, 0);
    opacity: 0;
    right: -150px;
    position: relative;
  }
}

.images {
  width: 600px;

  &__image {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
  }
}

.fs__icon {
    bottom :0px;
    right: 0px;
    margin-left: -45px;
    width:45px;
    height:45px;
    background: url(../fullscreen.png) no-repeat 0 0;
    z-index:2;
    opacity:1;
  }

.slick-slider {
  position: relative;

  .slick-list {
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  .slick-prev {
    display: none !important;
  }

  .slick-next {
    left: -32px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    background-color: #cc0000;
    border: none;
  }
}

.slick-lightbox-slick{
  .slick-next{
    display: none !important;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you add `id` properties to the divs? That would allow selecting each by `id`. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20644553/5872029) might also help you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checking if a div is visible within viewport using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20644029/checking-if-a-div-is-visible-within-viewport-using-jquery)

Comment: This is going to end up being a large scale project. Not sure if adding an id to each div would be the best answer

Comment: If it's a large scale project, individual `id`s could become bulky quickly, so that might indeed not solve it. Did you have a look at the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/moagrius/wN7ah/) in the answer I linked before? That looks like it might be of some help, although you may want to call the function on `scroll` rather than on `click`.

Comment: I have not looked into it yet.

Comment: Here is my fiddle so you can have a visual...https://jsfiddle.net/g2k0tjpw/5/

Comment: I'm not actually sure how to resolve this, as JSFiddle is giving me a hard time actually testing it. I'm getting an error in JSFiddle itself, not in my script. Anywho, here's an amended version, maybe you can get it to work, or use some of it to your advantage somehow: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qp23urqw/2/) I'm not making this an answer, as I can't test the code, so I'm not 100% sure it'll work.